# call time pass by reference seems to work in PHP5.5?

Tags: php, pass-by-reference

Quoting [the PHP reference manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) which states:

> as of PHP 5.4.0, call-time pass-by-reference was removed, so using it
>   will raise a fatal error

And yet it seems to work with [the following code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a50ab60759fcac7b1dfebfed1e755846ab66dd42) on PHP 5.5?:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

class parentClass
{
    function _funcA()
    {
        var_dump($this);
    }
}

class childClass extends parentClass
{
    function funcA()
    {
        call_user_func_array(array(&$this, '_funcA'), array());
    }
}

$test = new childClass();
$test->funcA();
```

So is the documentation wrong? Or is there some special caveat the documentation isn't mentioning? Why does this work when the documentation implies that it shouldn't?

edit: the fact that $this is an object doesn't seem to matter as the following still results in a fatal error:

```
<?php
function f($v) { return $v->x++; }
$a = new StdClass();
$a->x = 1;
$b = f(&$a);
var_dump($a, $b);
```

Comment: Perhaps because it's an object reference, and objects are always passed "by reference" rather than as copies: it's the specific instance that you're passing in the callback

Comment: Doesn't seem like the that's the case. I updated my orig post providing an example of where a call-time pass-by-reference on an object results in a fatal error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original code you are **not** passing `$this` by reference to `call_user_func_array`, it may *look* like it, but you are not.

You are passing in an array of a reference and a string, and an empty array.

So you are **not** passing a reference to the function, you are just passing 2 arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The removed thing is "call-time pass-by-reference", not "Passing by Reference".

You can still pass reference to function, but you need to define function parameter with '&'. When doing on function call, you must not use '&' before '$' of variable, that will cause warning(5.3) or error(5.4).

So, your simple function above will be fixed like this:

```
<?php
function f(&$v)        // '&' is added here
  { return $v->x++; }
$a = new StdClass();
$a->x = 1;
$b = f($a);            // '&' is removed here
var_dump($a, $b);
```

And, in your beginning case, is a different question. $this is a pointer to class instance itself, '&$this' will have same value. Object parameter in PHP5 is already pass by reference, you need not add '&' before them.

Comment: You're right that in my second example I don't *need* to do a call-time pass-by-reference but that doesn't change the fact that I *can't* - that attempting to do so results in a fatal error. The fact that it's an object doesn't prevent the fatal error from occurring either.

Comment: $this is object, will pass-by-reference, but `array(&$this, '_funcA')` is a 'constant', so there is no error reported. array() has no name(variable reference), you can't reuse it later.